# Remove language and note in LateX bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographystyle

I am writing a scientific article and I have issues with my bibliography. I use a provided template containing .bst files.

My problem is the following: I do not want the language ("en", "fr") and the notes to be printed in the bibliography.

My bibliography is exported from Zotero. It is a .bib file. I import my references using the following command at the end of the document:

```
\bibliography{POF_test}
```

where POF_test is the name of the .bib file. To remove the language specification I tried the following solutions found on forums:

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \clearfield{language}%
}
```

I also tried with `\clearlist`

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \clearlist{language}%
}
```

And eventually I tested:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=language,null]
    }
  }
}
```

Each time the code is placed before the `\begin{document}` command. However, none of these solutions have worked.

Concerning the notes, I succeeded in removing them modifying the .bst file:

```
FUNCTION {format.note}
{
#1
{ "" }
{…}
if$
}
```

I am sure that there is an easier way to do it but I did not found it. Moreover, I do not manage to do the same with the language.

Can someone, explain me why the command `\AtEveryBibitem` does not work for me ? How can I remove the language specification in the bibliography ?

Comment: There are two systems for generating bibliographies, Bibtex and Biblatex. They are different and cannot be used together. It seems like you are trying to combine them, which does not work. Either you should switch to Biblatex completely, and then use commands like `\AtEveryBibitem`, or use Bibtex and edit the entries in the `.bib` file manually to remove the unwanted fields. Note that if you want to submit a paper to a journal then using Biblatex may not be allowed.

Comment: Hello there! This is Tom from the Overleaf Support Team. Please note that I removed the [tag:overleaf] tag as this is not directly Overleaf-related. I hope you manage to solve the issue!